# How to get a sha256 hash code for a github repo?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, sha256

I am trying to build a condo package for a git hub repo which requires a "sha256" hash code how I can I obtained sha256 for a git repo example. https://github.com/jensengroup/fragbuilder

example is here:

```
source:
  url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/38/7c/be04cb1010161c5f32a0a3d7f79af492e98d0487814d8d1bd35ca257a41a/{{ name }}-{{ version }}.zip
  sha256: "bbd9fd380826c6cef78871f62b3fb8cf4a466fa99a32e61ea9ba839dc1833e5d"
```

this sha256 generated by the conda skeleton how I can get his for a git repo.

Comment: Are you talking about a commit hash? That's the long hexadecimal string you find on every commit.

Comment: @KlausD. I have updated the question I am not very sure if it belongs to a commit.

Comment: Obviously you need the SHA256 hash of that ZIP file. And BTW it does not make sense to parameterize the URL with name and version and have a fixed hash at the same time.

Comment: SO my question is that How we can generate that checksum Sha256

Comment: Download the ZIP file and run `sha256sum …` on it.

Comment: I already tried this but when I am using the generated hash sha256 in conda build its showing an error miss-match of sha256

Comment: Then please put what you have tried into the question, including the exact commands you used and the exact output.

Comment: Please include all relevant information on the post itself, and clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 14):

I solve the problem I am posting here what I have tried so that if anyone experiences the same problem can get help from here.

Rather zip file I downloaded the tar.gz source file from the release section of github repo.

```
fragbuilder-1.0.1.tar.gz
```

the command generates a stable sha256

```
shasum -a 256 fragbuilder-1.0.1.tar.gz
```

sha256 hash

```
sha256: edc718e09a72ae0ba2cc99d54a406d6034f71b572a19f85c408a22c5d63f117b
```

That can be used to meta.yaml to build a package.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to generate the sha256 automatically for any release published for a github repo you can use a very simple Github Action to do that. Here is an example I am using for one of my projects as I need the sha256 to publish to homebrew:

```
# release.yml - Automatic creation of sha256 for release tarball

name: goprox release action
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is publishing release ${{ github.ref_name }}
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
jobs:
  sha256:
    name: sha256
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Tarball url
        run: echo "${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/archive/refs/tags/${{ github.ref_name }}.tar.gz"
      - name: Create tarball sha256 
        run: curl -sL "${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/archive/refs/tags/${{ github.ref_name }}.tar.gz" | shasum -a 256 | cut -d " " -f 1
```